# How to make a loop to download a sequence of maps in R

Tags: r, loops, download, raster

I would like to create a loop in R to download a sequence of maps from a website. The problem is that I am able to download manually tiles of 2km<sup>2</sup>, but the area is quite big.

For example:
(https://avoin-karttakuva.maanmittauslaitos.fi/ortokuvat-ja-korkeusmallit/wcs/v2?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageID=ortokuva_mustavalko&SUBSET=E(678611,680026)&SUBSET=N(6933477,6934891)&format=image/tiff&SUBSET=time(%222003-12-31T00:00:00Z%22)

where N = northing and E = Easting.

So my idea is to create a loop that is able to download the tiles between the coordinates E(x,x<sub>1</sub>) and N(y,y<sub>1</sub>) every 2km<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: What have you tried so far?